# Can't apply margin-right to relatively positioned element

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am working in Vue to build a series of cards that scroll across a mobile screen in the x-direction.  It's sort of like a testimonial section where the user can scroll right or left to see new testimonials.

I am able to apply a left margin to the cards however I can't add a right margin to the final card so that it can be scrolled into the center of the screen.

Here is the code sandbox: https://6ky1r.csb.app/
Note, this is designed for the mobile but you can see the issue on the desktop view also.

When you scroll all the way to the right the white background of the card goes all the way to the edge which is not desired.

```
<template>
  <div class="homePageTwo">
    <div class="cardHolder">
      <div class="cardSpace" v-for="card in cards" :key="card.index">
        <SlidingCard :title="card.title" :content="card.content" :icon="card.icon"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SlidingCard from "./SlidingCard.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    SlidingCard
  },
  data() {
    return {
      cards: [
        {
          title: "Food Services",
          content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        },
        {
          title: "Assisted Living",
          content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        },
        {
          title: "Retail",
          content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        },
        {
          title: "Education",
          content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.homePageTwo {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f7f8fc;
  padding-top: 3rem;
}
.cardHolder {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}
.cardSpace {
  padding: 2.5rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
</style>
```

```
<template>
  <div class="slidingCard">
    <div class="photoHolder">
      <img class="homePageOneImg" :alt="alt" :src="icon">
    </div>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ content }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "SlidingCard",
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  props: ["title", "content", "icon", "alt"]
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.slidingCard {
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  width: 60vw;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}
.photoHolder {
  height: 10rem;
  line-height: 10rem;
  border-radius: 90px;
  background-color: #f7f8fc;
  width: 8rem;
  margin: auto;
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  white-space: normal !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

I see a couple of simple fixes:

**Option 1:**
Adding `margin: 0 1rem;` to the cardHolder.

**Option 2:**
Add a hidden border after the last child. See [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-nobel-jqw2v).

Comment: This doesn't quite work.  The margin that is added causes the background color to constantly be visible at the edges.  The desired result is for the card space div to occupy the full screen width, and the last card should have a right margin so that it can be aligned in the center of the screen.

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer for another possible solution.

Comment: I will mark this as correct.  I ended up changing the component around a big and using last-child with padding.